# Is there a way to determine if two photos are identical, ignoring relative differences in image sizes?

Tags: file-management, photo-management, resize

Is there a reliable way to determine if two or more photos are the same, regardless of relative image size differences?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I have a collection of photos and some of them are simply downsizings of an original one. I would like to be able to automatically remove the downsized pictures and keep the original only. This happened because through the years I automatically backed up pictures shared in social media which resized the original - so I ended up with lots of resizes of the original photos.

Comment: Could you please use an English word or phrase that communicates what 'modulo' means in another language?

Comment: In your question, are you using this word "modulo" to mean "ignoring" or "apart from"? I have only ever encountered "modulo" in the context of dividing numbers and getting the remainder.

Comment: If so, I have used [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info) (on Windows) to do what you want.

Comment: "modulo" means "congruent to", or "after eliminating common factors". In math terms, 9 == 19 == 29 (_modulo_ 10). See also [Meaning of "modulo the fact"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/) (at English.SE)

Comment: I reconciled a huge set once by resizing them to very small pics/thumbnails, 32px wide, saving in a lossless format, then comparing MD5 signatures for all the files to find dupes, noting filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to steal @osullic comment.

> If so, I have used VisiPics (on Windows) to do what you want.

I have tested it a bit and it is doing a decent job. It is a really small application for windows. It can be improved a lot, but it works.

It marks as green if it feels it is an exact duplicate, and some other colors like orange if it is just similar.

Another option: duplicate-finder.com It assumes the bigger file is the original, but it makes a good job.

This two, unfortunately, seems to be discontinued.

Another that does the job is pixiple.

There are some other alternatives, which I still need to test. https://alternativeto.net/software/duplicate-photo-finder/