# How to organize photos efficiently (in terms of 'naming', 'tagging' and FOSS)?

Tags: photo-management

I have thousands of photos in multiple directories. Any tool or idea to organize them properly will be helpful.

Here is the details:

I have been ignorant all along about organizing those until recently when I tried to search a particular picture. However, I am using a bash script to find and delete duplicates (`md5 hash data`) and `imagemagick's identify` to extract `EXIF:DateTimeOriginal`. My image file names are like `yyyymmdd_serialNo.extension`. For example,

> 20210101_1.JPG

Most of the pictures made on my DLSR and iPhone have those info except for the ones which are very old. Even `fdupes` can't detect the duplicates of those. I could not but rely on my visual capabilities (a pain you can imagine). Any thoughts to improve what I am doing? I appreciate

Comment: Related questions: [What software is focused on reviewing and organizing images?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/4212), [What's a good application for file and folder for organizing large amounts of images on Linux?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/10596), [Organize photos for many overlapping projects](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/109132), among others. The site's search for "[organizing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=organizing)" returns many possibly useful questions and answers.

Comment: @scottbb: Thank you, Scot. I will check them out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What software is focused on reviewing and organizing images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/what-software-is-focused-on-reviewing-and-organizing-images)

Comment: I think it's important to ask... how do _you_ want them to be organised? By location? By date? By subject? By camera? By colour/B&W? I would organise the photos differently to you, I'm sure.

Comment: @osullic: I do not know exactly what organization method will serve me best in the future. If you have experience about it, I will appreciate if you share with all of us. I have never thought about it seriously until recently and it is a mess now. Right now I am organizing them according to the dates and renaming the files by a bash script. Each file precede by the date it was made on.

Comment: @MichaelC: Thank you. The FOSS recommendation is ultimately what I will look forward to. Right now, I am more focused on renaming the files properly so that I can search and find them from the pool efficiently.

Comment: @Pladin before you go too far with your renaming... just want to confirm that you are aware of the Exif date, and how it can be different to the file date

Comment: @osullic: Yes, the bash script actually compares md5 hash data to find duplicates and organizes according to the extracted `EXIF:DateTimeOriginal`. Most of the pictures made on my DLSR and iPhone have those info except for the ones which are very old. `fdupes` can't detect the duplicates of those. I could not but rely on my visual capabilities. Any thought to improve what I am doing? I appreciate

Comment: @Pladin that information is important to the question to help guide useful answers. Please edit your question to include that info, so it's more visible to people who might be able to answer. Thanks! =)

Comment: @scottbb: Thanks, I will try to edit the question. Actually, I posted everything in the first place but got flagged (or whatever) and had to take it down.

Comment: Take a look also at this question... [Is there a way to determine if two photos are identical, ignoring relative differences in image sizes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/103606)

Comment: @osullic: Sorting my last directory then I will be done for now. It came down to **184 GB** with more than **37 thousand images**. So far I have realized that it is extremely difficult to to find duplicates if metadata changes. It is quite understandable. `md5 has data` did a very good job after `fdupes` and `fslint` failed. I believe other programs are very much alike (based on the comments I read). I will continue to look forward to finding better organizing styles. At least, I have some control now :)

Comment: @Pladin you could always take fewer photos ;-)

Comment: @osullic: I wish I could. But lessons learned the hard way. I will organize the newer photos systematically from now on :-)

Comment: This question is more about file management than it is about photography, per se.

Answer (score 3):

There is an element of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) in the question. What you probably want is not organizing photos efficiently, but **finding** photos efficiently. Framed that way, deduplication has approximately zero benefit (if you're out of disk space a bigger disk is a better answer).

Framed as improving the finding of photos, any first step is pretty much a step in the right direction (or at least not a regression) whereas deduplication has a high potential for permanently making a picture unfindable...human fallibility works like that.

With pictures produced by digital cameras, EXIF data comes more or less for free, and so that's a place to start. There are many options for cataloging pictures. I happen to use Darktable for that because I also use it for editing pictures. But any catalog program that stores EXIF data in a database table when pictures are imported is worth considering.

The problem with EXIF data is that it is (in ordinary practice) entirely technical. It does not contain information about the contents from the standpoint of what we humans care about.

Tags are the most straight forward way to add information that matters in terms of what we do with photographs. The great thing about tags is that two similar tags on the same picture don't make a difference -- a picture with "dog", "dogs", and "canines" is easier to find. Even better tags are not mutually exclusive. A relational model with a field "color" won't allow "green" and "brown" and "blue" a the same time. The tags model does.

If you start tagging new pictures today, you have improved **finding** pictures. There's no need to go back and boil the ocean by organizing every single image. At least right away. Instead, images can be organized bit by bit as needed. Keep in mind that you will never want to find most of your images.

Just importing the images into a "cataloging" application will go a long way because EXIF typically contains date information and usually you will have an approximate timeframe for when the picture was made.

As your tagging grows, you will also have some idea of how your tagging practice has improved over time. (For me simpler and flatter is better).

Comment: Really good for recognizing the oblique problem of _finding what you have_ vs. _processing incoming_.